# How do I stop network operations in Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, networking, stream

In my app I download images from the Web with `Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, null);` where `inputStream` is taken with this code:

```
connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
connection.setConnectTimeout(1000);
connection.setReadTimeout(1000);
imagesRenderer.downloadStream = connection.getInputStream();
```

Images may be large, and the problems begin when I want to stop the image downloading.
Calling `inputStream.close()` doesn't work neither directly from UI thread due to `NetworkOnMainThreadException` nor with the background thread, as in the following code:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}).start();
```

This one just doesn't seem to work: the operations finished as if there was no attempt to stop it.

So I'm wondering, is there a way to close a network stream immediately or I have to implement images downloading in another way? What's the right way if so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, solved the problem using a buffer between image downloading and creating a drawable:

```
downloadStream = connection.getInputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
while (!needsCancel) {
    int r = downloadStream.read(buffer);
    if (r == -1) break;
    out.write(buffer, 0, r);
}
d = Drawable.createFromStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()), null);
```